# KnockoutJS: collecting values of checkboxes and selects in array together

Tags: knockout.js

I'm really pulling my hair out on this one. I need to loop over some selected items, consisting both of checkboxes and select lists, and compile an array of the selected models.

This is eluding me because `checked` and the select's `value` work differently. I was trying to simply store the selected option in a parent model (with a selectedOption observable). This worked fine for `<select>` because it saved a reference to the model, but with checkboxes, it would only save a boolean value.

I tried setting a flag on the model itself, which is fine for checkboxes, but I can't access individual options to let them know that they're the current selection in a `select` list.

All models populating checkboxes and dropdown lists are of the same type, I'm just displaying them differently depending on certain internal properties.

How can I simply collect the models of all selected options from both checkboxes and select lists?

Edit: Adding samples. There's an `Item` model which is the parent for an `Option` model.

```
function ItemModel(vm, item) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = item.name;
    self.description = item.description;
    self.options = ko.observableArray(mapOptions(vm, item.options) || []);
    self.selectedOption = ko.observable();
}

function OptionModel(vm, option) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = option.name;
    self.sku = option.sku || "";
    self.price = ko.observable();
}
```

Markup/bindings (in which I foolishly thought I could set the checked value of the checkbox to simply be the model). If there's a single `Option` I use a checkbox, if more than one, I use a select list.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedOption, checkedValue: $data" />

<select data-bind="value: selectedOption,
options: options,
optionsText: item.name
optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

Again, the `<select>` works as expected: the value is a reference to the currently selected `Option`, which means I can use that data elsewhere in the app (to tally up a summary of the customer's order). The checkbox, however, only saves a boolean value.

Comment: In the end, you just want an array of the selected objects? Does the order in the array matter? Can you provide a sample of an object that would be represented as a select, and one that would be a checkbox?

Comment: Hi Roy thanks. Code samples added. Ideally, it would run top to bottom, keeping things in order. I'd considered some kind of computed in the ViewModel that would check if something was a checkbox or not, but that just seemed janky. It just feels like there should be a consistent way to loop over form selections and get the same kinds of data, whether a select list or a checkbox...

Comment: You can use `checkedValue` to get a observableArray

Comment: Indeed I can, but I can't write to one in the same way via the `<select>`. Checked writing to an array will automatically add/remove the correct index. Select chokes on it.

Comment: PS: I don't understand the relation between checkbox and select, can you use two observableArray monitoring checkbox and select separately, and use another ko.computed merge two arrays?

Comment: So the way it works is if an `Item` only has a single `Option` I show a checkbox. Makes sense: do you want to select this option, or not. If an `Item` has multiple `Options`, then show a dropdown. I could totally run two separate processes, based on what the input element is (checkbox or select) but that's a bit messy because now I'm basing data decisions on view elements, and since they're both just point back to the same kinds of data (`Items` with nested `Options`) I was hoping for something more DRY.

Comment: It would probably be nice if Knockout would work nicely with this. Perhaps you could open an issue in Github.

Answer (score 1):

I think the preferred way to solve this is with a custom binding. Here's one I put together that should do what you need.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.valueWhenChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        if (!ko.isWritableObservable(valueAccessor().model)) {
            throw Error("model must be an observable");
        }
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var model = valueAccessor().model;
            model(element.checked ? valueAccessor().value : undefined);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        element.checked = valueAccessor().model() === valueAccessor().value;
    }
};

function ItemModel() {
    this.options = ko.observableArray(["test"]);
    this.selectedOption = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ItemModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="valueWhenChecked: { model: selectedOption, value: options()[0] }" />

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you add an `isSelected` member, with a subscription that sets `selectedOption` to the first option when true? Then use the `isSelected` as your checkbox value.